# Table Manipulation / Splitting to different files

Tags: python, arrays, perl, awk

Would like to change the split the below table to other files.

```
    Measure1    Measure2    Measure3    Measure4
Boy1    A1  B1  C1  D1
Boy2    A2  B2  C2  D2
Boy3    A3  B3  C3  D3
Boy4    A4  B4  C4  D4
Boy5    A5  B5  C5  D5
Boy6    A6  B6  C6  D6
Boy7    A7  B7  C7  D7
Boy8    A8  B8  C8  D8
Boy9    A9  B9  C9  D9
Boy10   A10 B10 C10 D10
BoyN    AN  BN  CN  DN
```

A total of N files should be generated, where:-

File1 named Boy1.

```
A1  C1
B1  D1
```

File2 named Boy2.

```
A2  C2
B2  D2
```

File3 named Boy3.

```
A3  C3
B3  D3
```

and so forth.

The only method that I tried was using R, but I would like to do that using Unix platform.

R method:

```
Boy1=matrix(data=c(A1,B1,C1,D1), nrow=2, ncol=2)
Boy2=matrix(data=c(A2,B2,C2,D2), nrow=2, ncol=2)
.
.
.
```

Comment: What's your field separator in file Boy1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $2,$4 RS $3,$5 >$1; close($1)}' file
```

Or with a tab as output field separator:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $2,$4 RS $3,$5 >$1; close($1)}' OFS='\t' file
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: To be a bit pedantic, I would change `NR` by `FNR` and `RS` by `ORS`. This allows the user to felxibly change `ORS` if he wants.

Comment: Yes, you could switch to `FNR`. `ORS` is a good idea.

Comment: I wouldn't bother changing `NR` to `FNR` since it's just 1 input file but I'd definitely change `RS` to `ORS`.